# barcode scanner programming in C#

Tags: c#, barcode-scanner

I need to develop a simple attendance system for a company. I am interested to develop this software in C# because I heard that .NET framework provides Barcode Scanner Libraries which makes this task easier. I have been given barcode scanner of AURORA. I have configured this scanner with my system and it reads when i swipe card before it.
I have no idea how to capture barcode information!! This is a completely new task for me and I don't know the methods which I can use to read barcode.
I know that Scaner usually read data as string, keeps it in clipboard and paste it in
active editbox or whatever it active.
For example, if I open notepad and scan card, in notepad I see the number 00004 (which i think is barcode)...
I have few questions:
**1. What is the best way to read barcode value which appears on editbox (My application will have an editbox), I need to control the Scanner Event so that It should not paste barcode value in editbox by iteself, rather than I will use that value...

2. What will be the code which will fire an event when someone swipe card?**

Kindly provide some working sample code(C#).Your help will be highly appreciated.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    SerialPort _serialPort;

    // delegate is used to write to a UI control from a non-UI thread
    private delegate void SetTextDeleg(string text);

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // all of the options for a serial device
        // can be sent through the constructor of the SerialPort class
        // PortName = "COM1", Baud Rate = 19200, Parity = None, 
        // Data Bits = 8, Stop Bits = One, Handshake = None
        _serialPort = new SerialPort("COM1", 19200, Parity.None, 8, StopBits.One);
        _serialPort.Handshake = Handshake.None;
        _serialPort.DataReceived += new SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(sp_DataReceived);
        _serialPort.ReadTimeout = 500;
        _serialPort.WriteTimeout = 500;
        _serialPort.Open();
    }

    private void btnStart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Makes sure serial port is open before trying to write
        try
        {
            if (!_serialPort.IsOpen)
                _serialPort.Open();

            _serialPort.Write("SI\r\n");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Error opening/writing to serial port :: " + ex.Message, "Error!");
        }
    }

    void sp_DataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
        Thread.Sleep(500);
        string data = _serialPort.ReadLine();
        this.BeginInvoke(new SetTextDeleg(si_DataReceived), new object[] { data });
    }

    private void si_DataReceived(string data)
    {
        textBox1.Text = data.Trim();
    }

    private TextBox textBox1;
    private Label label1;
    private RichTextBox richTextBox1;
    private Button button1;
}
```

Comment: What have you tried? Do you have any source code? Did you do any form of research? This question is practically non-answerable because it lacks information

Comment: Maybe you could start by reading your scanner's documentation then come back and ask something more * targeted*.

Answer (score 3):

Well, usually MSRs (Magnetric Stripe Readers) will dump the output to your `STDIN` - which means it acts like a keyboard.

You'll have to capture keyboard events in your application in order for it to read the data, start with that.

BTW:

How about your *try* working out some code before asking for samples?

Comment: I added C# code in my post which I found from internet. It basically reads serial input and set the output string(barcode) to Form Textbox.
But I think its not working because its the scanner which paste barcode into textbox.
Can you now tell me in detail that how can i capture keyboard events in my application so that it does not paste barcode in textbox, and i can use that value where i want!

Comment: @NidaSulheri is the MSR connected to your PC via a serial port?

Comment: Scanner is connected to my PC via USB port.

Comment: So how about you do some more research on how your MSR works. You don't even need to open a serial port for that.

Comment: I read [this](http://nicholas.piasecki.name/blog/2009/02/distinguishing-barcode-scanners-from-the-keyboard-in-winforms/) article. I have downloaded its sample project and loaded it in VS 2010. Actually I am not be able to understand how i should make use of that code? Can you please guide me? I just need to know that by calling which method will listens to scan event...

Comment: @RoyGoode it is a MSR as the OP pointed out 'What will be the code which will fire an event when someone swipe card?' which means its a CARD READER.